# Get last three months from a list of month

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, time

I have to find the last three month from a list of month.

**For example:-**

List of month is:-

Jun16,Mar16,Dec16,Jan17,Oct16,Nov16

So i need

```
Jan17
Dec16
and Nov16
```

Last three months

Is there is any way to find?

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: month name string length 3 will be fixed ?

Comment: and month list will be in string format or will be in array format ?

Comment: Yes, month name length 3 is fixed

Comment: It is an array format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way, it will work 100%

```
<?php

$month_arr = array('Jun16','Mar16','Dec16','Jan17','Oct16','Nov16');

/* Convert dates in y-m-d format */
foreach ($month_arr as $key => $ma) {
    $output    = str_split($ma, 3);
    $full_date = $output[1].'-'.date('m', strtotime($output[0])).'-01';
    $months[]  = $full_date;
}

/* Now sort all dates in DESC order */
$dates = array();
foreach ($months as $u)
 {
    $dates[] = $u;
 }
array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $months);

/* Get latest 3 months */
$last_three_months = array_slice($months, 0, 3);

/* Convert last 3 months into required format */
foreach($last_three_months as $lm)
{
    $parsed_last_three_months[] = date('My',strtotime($lm));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($parsed_last_three_months);

?>
```

Hope it will work. and please let me know if it`s DONE :)

Comment: Was Good Question :)